# reinterpret_cast<std::string*> cause segmentation fault on gcc but works on clang

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

both gcc and clang version is 11, here is the sample code

```
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>


void store_rvalue_string(std::byte* buffer, std::string&& value) {
    *reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(buffer) = std::move(value);
}


int main() {
    auto buffer = new std::byte[1024];
    std::string str = "hello";
    store_rvalue_string(buffer, std::move(str));
}
```

Comment: This is not a valid C++ code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a strict aliasing violation, and thus UB.

A less formal answer is that you're calling `std::basic_string::operator=` on a piece of memory for which the `string` constructor was never called in the first place.

My guess is that on Clang the memory happened to be filled with zeroes, and that a string filled with zero bytes counts as empty on your standard library implementation.

The right solution is to use placement-new, to create a *new* object (by calling its constructor):

```
new(buffer) std::string(std::move(str));
```

Comment: ... and `new std::byte[1024];` could be replaced with `new std::byte[sizeof(std::string)];`

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bfWqMqMGs) or with two [`unique_ptr`'s](https://godbolt.org/z/YYf1jjboW)